# Openlayers zooming and panning restrictions don't work

Tags: openlayers-2

Consider the following example (I tried to keep it as simple as possible).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map { width: 800px; height: 600px; }
    </style>

    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init(){

          var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
            "OpenStreet Maps"
          );

          var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
            -1500000, 4000000, 5600000, 11000000
          );

          var map= new OpenLayers.Map({
            div: 'map',
            layers: [layer],
            maxExtent: extent,
            restrictedExtent: extent,
            maxScale: 60000000,
            controls: [
              new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
              new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
              new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
              new OpenLayers.Control.Scale()
            ]
          });

          map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="init()">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As the `OSM` map is in the Spherical Mercator Projection, the bounds `(-1500000, 4000000, 5600000, 11000000)` should cover most of Europe. I set these bounds both as the `maxExtent` and the `restrictedExtent` of the map.

Furthermore, I set `maxScale` to `60 M`.

After launching this example, the map really centers to Europe and restricts panning to other parts of the World. But, it absolutely disregards the `maxScale` attribute and allows zooming far away.

Now, I try to remove the `restrictedExtent`. I should be able to pan the map freely. This is true. However, now the `zoomToMaxExtent()` doesn't work, although the `maxExtent` is still set!

How come neither `maxScale` nor `zoomToMaxExtent()` would work in this example? Am I just gravely misunderstanding the OpenLayers documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this with OL 2.11, so you need to change OpenLayers URL from http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js to http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js and use the following code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #map { width: 800px; height: 600px; }
</style>

<script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){

      var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
        "OpenStreet Maps", null, {
        resolutions: [19567.87923828125, 9783.939619140625,
            4891.9698095703125, 2445.9849047851562, 1222.9924523925781,
            611.4962261962891, 305.74811309814453, 152.87405654907226,
            76.43702827453613, 38.218514137268066, 19.109257068634033,
            9.554628534317017, 4.777314267158508, 2.388657133579254,
            1.194328566789627, 0.5971642833948135, 0.29858214169740677,
            0.14929107084870338, 0.07464553542435169],
        serverResolutions: [156543.03390625, 78271.516953125,
            39135.7584765625, 19567.87923828125, 9783.939619140625,
            4891.9698095703125, 2445.9849047851562, 1222.9924523925781,
            611.4962261962891, 305.74811309814453, 152.87405654907226,
            76.43702827453613, 38.218514137268066, 19.109257068634033,
            9.554628534317017, 4.777314267158508, 2.388657133579254,
            1.194328566789627, 0.5971642833948135, 0.29858214169740677,
            0.14929107084870338, 0.07464553542435169]
        }
      );

      var extent = [-1500000, 4000000, 5600000, 11000000];

      var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: 'map',
        layers: [layer],
        maxExtent: extent,
        restrictedExtent: extent,
        controls: [
          new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
          new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
          new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
          new OpenLayers.Control.Scale()
        ]
      });

      map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It should work as you expected.

Comment: Why is that laundry list of resolutions necessary? Couldn't we just set a `minResolution` instead?